# Limit of algebraic function avoiding l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: analysis, limits

> Find
>   $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[3]{1 + x^{2} + x^{3}} -x$$

Comment: @white: I have edited the question, please if this is what you wanted to post or not.

Comment: Hi ? Please ? Homework ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: @white: As Arturo, always keeps mentioning, please pose the question in a more polite form. This is like asking a homework question. We would like to know what you have tried and where you are finding difficulty.

Comment: lol..ok i am sorry if i am rude..

Comment: @white: We, would like to know what you have tried that all.

Comment: i have tried by multiplying {(〖1+x^2+x^3)〗^(1/3) to get rid the 1/3..but i seems to get bac the answer of 1..as if i substitute infinity on the earlier equation..the answer is the same is equal to 1..so am i doin correctly or....wrong???

Comment: yup..it is the correct interpretation..but if the answer is 1..i juz substitute the infinity to x..than i get the answer??

Comment: um, I think the answer should be 1/3, not 1.

Comment: izit??can u please teach me hw??@Willie Wong♦

Comment: The answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.  Unless you use either Taylor series or L'Hospital's rule, it will be a bit messy. (But is doable with the difference of cubes identity and such)

Comment: In general, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{x^n+ax^{n-1}+O(x^{n-2})}-x=\frac{a}{n}$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\ $ It's simply a first derivative: $\: $ changing variables $\rm\ x\to 1/x\ $ transforms it to

$$\rm\displaystyle\ \lim_{x\to\ 0^{+}}\ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\ =\ f\:'(0) \ \ \ for\ \ \ f(x) = (1+x+x^3)^{1/3}$$

Now it is easy to calculate $\rm\ f\:'(0)\ =\ 1/3\ $ by direct evaluation (it's not indeterminate). Namely

$$\rm f\:'(x)\ =\ \frac{d}{dx}\ (1+x+x^3)^{1/3}\ =\ \frac{1+3\ x^2}{3\ (1+x+x^3)^{2/3}}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ f\:'(0)\ =\  \frac{1}3$$

Note that this method employs only knowledge of the *definition* of the derivative and basic *rules* for calculating derivatives of polynomial and powers. It does not employ more advanced techniques such as L'Hospital's rule, or (binomial) power series expansions, etc.

Comment: is this lopital??

Comment: @white: The above easy calculation of $\rm\ f\:'(0)\ $ doesn't use L'Hopital's rule (it's not indeterminate). While there is indeed a close relationship between L'Hospital's rule, derivatives, Taylor's formula, the mean-value-theorem, etc., that doesn't imply that use of the latter implies use of L'Hospital's rule. The above answer uses only the *definition* of the derivative and the basic *rules* for calculating derivatives.

Comment: I like this answer, +1.  To explain something white, this actually is L'hopitals rule, but not quite.  I say not quite because Bill's argument actually shows that L'Hopitals Rule follows immediately from the definition of the derivative when the denominator is $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more elementary way using the difference of cubes identity.  (It is not as elegant as the Taylor series presented by Willie Wong, but requires less background)

Since $x=\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}$, we are looking at $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}$.Recall that the cubic identity $a^{3}-b^{3}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{2}+ab+b^{2}\right)$, which tells us that

$$\left(\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}\right)^{3}-\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}\right)^{3}$$
$$=\left(\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}\right)\cdot \left(\left(1+x^{2}+x^{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}\cdot\left(1+x^{2}+x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(x^{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$

and hence

$$\frac{1+x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}+x^{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+x\cdot\left(1+x^{2}+x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^{2}}=\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}.$$

Divide the top and bottom of the left hand side by $x^{2}$ to find $$\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+1}=\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}.$$

Since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+1=3$$ 
we see by the quotient rule for limits $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[3]{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Hope that helps,

**Edit:**  This faq question: [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1)  was made shortly after this post to help answer it more generally.

Comment: hey..thx for the info..but unfortunately i'm not so understand about this method..abit confusing as from the 3rd part of ur solution,the x has been forfited n i duno where to cancel it off..sry bro i not so good in maths..XD

Comment: Which part exactly?  I might be able to explain better.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: you can rewrite the terms inside the limit as

$$ x \cdot \left( \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{x} + 1} - 1\right) $$

for the term underneath the cube-root, use the Taylor expansion of the cube-root function near the value 1:

$$ \sqrt[3]{1 + y} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}y - \frac{1}{9} y^2 + \ldots $$

Comment: bionomial???ok..i try it nw..thx for ur help..

Comment: ermm,@Willie Wong♦ ,i am not so sure about the taylor expansion as u mention..can u explain more on hw to apply it on the cube roots??

Comment: The Taylor expansion of (1+x)^k starts with 1+kx, even if k is not an integer.  For this problem you only need the $y/3$ term.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series to refresh your memory on the Taylor/binomial expansion for (1+x)^k.

Answer (score 3):

A very similar question was asked recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/limit-involving-as-x-to-infty-of-sqrt5x5-3x4-17-x/22104#22104)...

The limit follows immediately upon showing, using the mean value theorem, that
$$
\sqrt[3]{{\bigg(x + \frac{1}{3}\bigg)^3 }} - \sqrt[3]{{\bigg(x + \frac{1}{3}\bigg)^3  - \bigg(\frac{x}{3} - \frac{{26}}{{27}}\bigg)}} \to 0
$$
as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I hope you understand where the term $(x + \frac{1}{3})^3  - (\frac{x}{3} - \frac{{26}}{{27}})$ comes from.

Comment: nope..i am noob maths..lol

Comment: @white: It is equal to $x^3 + x^2 +1$.

Answer (score 0):

For such problems, quite often it pays off to use the identity

$a^b = \exp[ b * \log(a)]$

because then one can apply all his/her knowledge about exp and log.

Comment: Can you explain?  I don't see how you use this for this example unless you expand $e^{b\log a}=1+b\log a+\frac{1}{2}(b\log a)^2+\cdots$ and then expand the $\log$'s into their power series as well.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The comment was for an earlier version of the question which looked quite a bit different [$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1 + x^2 + x^3)^{1/3 -x}$].