# Limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty} 3\left(\sqrt{\strut x}\sqrt{\strut x-3}-x+2\right)$

Tags: limits

I have to compute this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to\infty} 3(\sqrt{\strut x}\sqrt{\strut x-3}-x+2)$$

wolfram alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B3%20(Sqrt%5Bx%5D%20Sqrt%5Bx%20-%203%5D%20-%20x%20%2B%202)%2C%20x%20-%3E%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D%5D) that answer is $\frac{3}{2}$, but I can't get why. Does anyone know how to get this limit?

Comment: Here are two very similar questions:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/limit-of-algebraic-function-avoiding-lhopitals-rule/22943#22943  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/limit-of-algebraic-function-avoiding-lhopitals-rule/22943#22943

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two standard techniques work: multiply and divide by the conjugate, then divide both numerator and denominator by the highest power of $x$.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}3\left(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x-3} - x+2\right) &= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2-3x} - (x-2)\right)\\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2-3x}-(x-2))(\sqrt{x^2-3x}+(x-2))}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+ (x-2)} \\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^2-3x) - (x-2)^2}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+(x-2)}\\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2 - 3x - x^2 + 4x - 4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x} + (x-2)}\\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x - 4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+(x-2)}\\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}(x-4)}{\frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{x^2-3x}+(x-2))}\\
&= 3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {1 - \frac{4}{x}}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{3}{x}} + 1 - \frac{2}{x})}\\
&= 3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+1}\right) = \frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: That is the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$$ 3 (\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x-3} -x +2 ) =
3 (\sqrt{x^2-3 x} -x +2 ) = 3 [x (\sqrt{1 -3/x} -1) +2 ]$$
$$=3 [x (1 -3/2x + O(x^{-2}) -1) +2 ] = 3/2 + O(x^{-1})$$
which implies that the limit is $3/2$.

Comment: Not sure if OP will understand this, +1 anyway!

Comment: +1 and two comments: first I think $O(x^{-1})$ is better than $O(x)^{-1}. Secondly, in the above we say that the first expression is of *the class* $3/2 + O(x^{-1})$ which imply the limit - we can not take the limit of the class (it might be confusing).

Comment: @AD: thank you for the comments. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just noticed I forgot to press +1.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\ $ It is simply a first derivative: $\: $ changing variables $\rm\ x\to 1/x\ $ transforms it to

$$\rm\displaystyle\ 3\ \lim_{x\to\ 0}\ \frac{\sqrt{1-3x}+2\ x-1}{x}$$

But this $\rm\ lim\ $ has the form of a derivative, namely it is simply

$$\rm\displaystyle\ \lim_{x\to\ 0}\ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\ =\ f\:'(0) \quad\ \ \ for\quad\ f(x)\ =\ \  \sqrt{1-3x}+2\ x-1$$

Now it is easy to directly calculate that $\rm\ f\:'(0)\ =\ 1/2\ $ so the original limit $\to 3/2\:.\:$ Note that this solution employs only knowledge of the *definition* of the derivative and basic *rules* for calculating derivatives of polynomials and powers. It does *not* employ related more advanced techniques such (binomial) power series or Taylor series, l'Hôpital's rule, the mean-value theorem, etc.

Comment: you mean $f(x) = \sqrt{1-3x}+2x$ right?

Comment: @App: Either works since they differ by 1 so have the same derivative.

Comment: yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$(\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x-3} - x)(\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x-3} + x) = -3x$$

$3/2$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/limit-of-algebraic-function-avoiding-lhopitals-rule/22943#22943) MSE page, your question is similar.  Notice your limit can be rewritten as $$6+3\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2-3x}-x\right)$$ but in general we have that 
 $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0}-x=\frac{a_n}{n}$$ which follows from [l'hopitals rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).  Hence the answer to your problem is $$6-\frac{9}{2}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}3\left(\sqrt{x\vphantom{3}}\sqrt{x-3}-x+2\right)
&=6+3\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x\vphantom{3}}\sqrt{x-3}-x\right)\\
&=6+3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-3x}{\sqrt{x\vphantom{3}}\sqrt{x-3}+x}\\
&=6-9\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac3x}+1}
\end{align}
$$