# Proving limit at infinity of a rational function

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970/finding-the-limit-of-fracqnpn-where-q-p-are-polynomials)

I need to prove these statements:

Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jx^j$ , $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m}b_jx^j$.

- $$\deg(g)\gt \deg(f) \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
- $$\deg(g)= \deg(f) \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
- $$\deg(f)\gt \deg(g) \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\pm \infty$$

Is there any proof that would help me in all three statements, so that my answer can be shorter? I'm pretty sure I know how to do it, but I am trying to think of a cleaver way to shorten my answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way?

I will solve you the first one, and you do the others.

So, we have $f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ and $g(x)=b_mx^m+...+b_0$. Given that $\deg(g(x))>\deg(f(x))$, it follows that $m>n$.

Now, let us take a look on that required limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_nx^n+...+a_0}{b_mx^m+...+b_0}$$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^m$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{a_nx^n}{x^m}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^m}}{\frac{b_mx^m}{x^m}+...+\frac{b_0}{x^m}}=\frac{0+...+0}{b_m+...+0}=\frac{0}{b_m}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that
$$f(x)=a_n\cdot x^n+a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1}+...+a_0$$
and also
$$g(x)=b_m\cdot x^m+b_{m-1}\cdot x^{m-1}+...+b_0$$

Now, there are three cases:

1. $n=m$

In this case, simply divide both polynomials by $x_n$ and $x_m$,and you get the limit as $\frac{a_n}{b_m}$.

1. $n<m$

If you repeat the same procedure, you will see that the denominator is greater than the numerator, so you get 0.

1. $n>m$

This is the reverse situation, numerator greater than the denominator, so it tends to infinity, but here, the sign depends on both values.

Comment: You need to use {} for more than one character in subscript/superscript.

Comment: aa thanks,i will consider it

Comment: Use \cdot for multiplication: $\cdot$ instead of $*$.