# Prove $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\dfrac{P_k(x)}{P_{k+1}(x)}=0$

Tags: limits, polynomials

Prove $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\dfrac{P_k(x)}{P_{k+1}(x)}=0$ by limits.

$P_k(x)$ is defined as a polynomial of degree $k$.

Comment: See [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970/finding-the-limit-of-fracqnpn-where-q-p-are-polynomials)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Methodology Proof**

Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^k$. Then the numerator has a constant term and a finite number of of terms of the form
$$ \frac{a_j}{x^j} \to 0 \quad \text{as } \quad x \to \infty$$
while the denominator has a linear term which goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$$p_k=a_1x^k+a_2x^{k-1}+...\\p_{k+1}=b_1x^{k+1}+b_2x^{k}+...\\  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p_{k}}{p_{k+1}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_1x^k+a_2x^{k-1}+...}{b_1x^{k+1}+b_2x^{k}+...}=\\\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^K(a_1+a_2\frac{1}{x}+a_3\frac{1}{x^2}...)}{x^{k+1}(b_1+b_2\frac{1}{x}+b_3\frac{1}{x^2}..)}=\\ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^k(a_1)}{x^{k+1}(b_1)}=\\ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(a_1)}{x^{1}(b_1)}\rightarrow 0  \\$$