# How to solve this limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n+2) (2n+1) }{ (n+1)^2}$

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^{2}}
$$

When I expand it gives:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{4n^{2} + 6n + 2}{n^{2} + 2n + 1}
$$
How can this equal $4$? Because if I replace $n$ with infinity it goes $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ only.

Comment: To continue (and finish) the approach in the question, note that $$\frac{4n^{2} + 6n + 2}{n^{2} + 2n + 1}=4\cdot\frac{1+\frac3{2n}+\frac1{2n^2}}{1+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}},$$ and rejoice...

Comment: See also: [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970/finding-the-limit-of-fracqnpn-where-q-p-are-polynomials)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle limits involving fractions you factor out the dominant term from top and bottom such that they cancel, by *dominant term*; I mean the term of highest degree, in this case it's $n^2$: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n^2 + 6n + 2}{n^2 + 2n + 1}$$
$$=\require\cancel\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2\cancel{n^2}\left(2 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\cancel{n^2}\left(1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2\left(2 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}}\tag{1}$$
$$=\frac{2\left(2 + 0 + 0\right)}{1 + 0 + 0}\tag{2}$$
$$=\color{blue}{4}$$

You get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ by making the observation that each of the fractions with $n$ or $n^2$ in the denominator will equal zero in the limit as $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n/n+2/n)(2n/n+1/n)}{(n/n+1/n)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2+2/n)(2+1/n)}{(1+1/n)^2}=\frac{(2+0)(2+0)}{(1+0)^2}=4$$

or 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2)(2n/n+1/n)}{(n/n+1/n)}=\frac{(2)(2+0)}{(1+0)}=4$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}=2\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2n+2-1}{n+1}
=2\left(2-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=2\left(2-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1/n}{1+1/n}\right)=2(2)=4$$

Comment: Nice method, (+1) I never would have thought to factor out the $2$ from the first bracket to get cancellation of $(n+1)$: well done!

Comment: That was basically my approach, too. :) But I think you're last step isn't necessary, since we can safely say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: rewrite it in the form
$$\frac{4+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

*With equivalents:*

At $\infty$, a polynomial is equivalent to its highest degree term, hence a rational function (quotient of polynomials) is equivalent to the  the ratio of the highest degree terms of its numerator and its denominator:
$$\frac{(2n+2) (2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\sim_\infty\frac{(2n)^2}{n^2}=4.$$