# limit of sequence with 5th root

Tags: limits

I need to solve this:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[5]{n^5+2n^4}
-\sqrt[5]{n^5-n^4}
$$
I am beginner in calculating limits of sequences. I would be happy if someone could show how to solve it or give me a hint so I could try to work it out by myself. Probably it's not complicated but I don't know how to get rid of this 5th roots.

Comment: You might want to copy [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45970/).

Comment: I'd factor $n^5$ outside the radical, and then use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to approximate each term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$a^5-b^5=(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)$$
Let $a=\sqrt[5]{n^5+2n^4}$ and $b=\sqrt[5]{n^5-n^4}$.

Comment: Correct. I think the $\lim = 1/4$ :D

Comment: @Hoping_VN the limit is $3/5$.

Comment: Sorry. 3/5 is correct :D