# Calculate limit with a lot of roots

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-\sqrt[\Large3]{1+5x}}{\sqrt[\Large5]{1+x}-\sqrt[\Large5]{1+2x}}$$

Multiplication by conjugate hasn't worked. I need a hint to start.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor series/approximations?

Comment: Suppose you write the first term in the numerator as $(1+2x)^{1/2}=\left((1+2x)^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}$. Then perhaps you could use the well-known identity,$$a^n-b^n=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$$

Comment: L'Hoptial might help. (It looks like it'd be very messy, though.)

Comment: @ClementC. it's forbidden for this task. And I'm not familiar.

Comment: Ah, Then my answer becomes sort of useless to you; but *what* are you allowed, then? (stating in your question what you can't use may be relevant)

Comment: Another [suggestion](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45985/170231), courtesy of Did.

Comment: @user170231: skimming it, it does rely on Taylor expansions (even though only up to first order), doesn't it?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, my mistake. I was in the process of searching for that older question/linking it in a comment when I heard the news.

Comment: @user170231 well, in any case it's a useful reference, to keep at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying L'Hospital's rule, we get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-\sqrt[3]{1+5x}}{\sqrt[5]{1+x}-\sqrt[5]{1+2x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2}{2\sqrt{1+2x}}-\frac{5}{3\sqrt[2/3]{1+5x}}}{\frac{1}{5\sqrt[4/5]{1+x}}-\frac{2}{5\sqrt[4/5]{1+2x}}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{2}{2}-\frac{5}{3}}{\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{5}}=\frac{\frac{-2}{3}}{\frac{-1}{5}}=\color{red}{\frac{10}{3}}$$

Comment: Straight forward, nice...+1

Comment: Rule of thumb: When your numerator and denominator both go to zero, L'Hospital's Rule is the first thing you should try.

Comment: @JerryGuern That's a matter of taste. My thumb is leaning towards Taylor.

Comment: @ClementC.  Your Taylor method below takes a bit more know-how than a student might have.  L'Hospital's Rule is harder to mess up.  And anyway, L'Hospital's Rule just amounts to Taylor-expanding the numerator and denominator separately so you can cancel some x's before plugging in x=0.

Comment: @JerryGuern The first thing I think of is the definition of the derivative. L'Hopital is often just a black box that gives no insight. (And I disagree that L'Hopital amounts to Taylor.)

Comment: @zhw.  If L'Hopital is a black box to you and you gained no insight from it, I suggest studying it more closely.  Try this exercise.  To calculate the limit of f(x)/g(x) as x->0, Taylor-expand f and g separately.  If f(0) and g(0) are both 0, you will be able to cancel x from the numerator and denominator.  In fact if the 0-nth derivs of f and g all equaled 0 at x=0, you'll be able to cancel x^(n+1).  The fraction that remain will clearly approach $f^{(n+1)}(0)/g^{(n+1)}(0)$.  And that's L'Hopital's rule, derived from Taylor expansion.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor series: when $x\to0$, we have, for any fixed  $\alpha$, $(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + o(x)$.

In your case,
$$
\frac{(1+2x)^{1/2} - (1+5x)^{1/3}}{(1+x)^{1/5}-(1+2x)^{1/5}} =
\frac{1+x + o(x) - (1+\frac{5}{3}x + o(x)))}{1+\frac{1}{5}x + o(x) -(1+\frac{2}{5}x + o(x))} = (\cdots)
$$

**Edit:** in a subsequent comment, it turns out the OP is not allowed to use Taylor series. I'm leaving this here, however, as it may be useful to other readers who don't have this constraint. (?)

Comment: Yeah, it's very useful. One day I will get this. Thank you.

Comment: @ValeryBaturin well, Taylor expansion to first order is basically a linear approximation: $f(x) \approx f(0) + f^\prime(0)x$. (And that's all that is needed here).

Comment: @ValeryBaturin: See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 0):

Just using the definition of the derivative: Let $a(x) = (1+2x)^{1/2},$ $ b(x) = (1+5x)^{1/3},$ $ c(x) = (1+x)^{1/5} ,d(x) = (1+2x)^{1/5}.$ The expression equals
$$\frac{a(x) - b(x)}{c(x) - d(x)} = \frac{(a(x)-a(1)) - (b(x)-b(1))}{(c(x)-c(1)) - (d(x)-d(1))}$$ $$ = \frac{(a(x)-a(1))/(x-1) - (b(x)-b(1))/(x-1)}{(c(x)-c(1))/(x-1) - (d(x)-d(1))/(x-1)}.$$

By definition of the derivative, the above has limit
$$\frac{a'(1)-b'(1)}{c'(1)-d'(1)},$$

an easy computation.

Comment: Essentially a rederivation of L'Hospital.

Comment: @martycohen I disagree. You can't derive L'Hopital this way, because in LHR there is no assumption that derivatives exist at the point in question. Note also this problem could be solved in the first few weeks of calculus with the method above, when L'Hopital is not available.