# Solving the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, indeterminate-forms

Recently, I am struggling to solve the limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x)$$ 
If I try to make some fraction with nominator $-x^4$ and some irrational denominator by multiplying, it becomes more complex. Can anyone help about this with more easier way?

Comment: Whats the answer given ? (If you have a book or something)

Comment: Thanks to @lab bhattacharjee, I found the answer by myself: -0.2

Comment: I have a much simpler solution actually.

Comment: I appreciate your support, please share it with us...

Comment: I have posted my solution. Please verify.

Comment: A few somewhat similar limits can be found on this site. For example, [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040) and some of the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040). You could also look at [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[6]{x^{6}+x^{5}}-\sqrt[6]{x^{6}-x^{5}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45970) and [the questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/45970).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Let $1/x=h\implies h\to0$

$$\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}=\sqrt[5]{\dfrac{1-h}{h^5}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[5]{1-h}}h$$

Now set $\sqrt[5]{1-h}=y\implies h=1-y^5$  to have $$-\lim_{y\to1}\dfrac{y-1}{y^5-1}=?$$

Comment: We can set $$\sqrt[5]{1-h}=1-y$$ as well

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}$ and $b=x$. Then\begin{align}\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x&=a-b\\&=\frac{(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)}{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}\\&=\frac{a^5-b^5}{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}\\&=\frac{-x^4}{\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}^4+\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}^3\,x+\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}^2\,x^2+\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}\,x^3+x^4}\\&=\frac{-1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}}x\right)^4+\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}}x\right)^3+\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}}x\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}}x+1}\\&=\frac{-1}{\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^4+\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^3+\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^2+\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}+1}\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{-1}{\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^4+\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^3+\left(\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}\,\right)^2+\sqrt[5]{1-\frac1x}+1}\\&=-\frac15.\end{align}

Comment: Actually, this way was the way I was scared for being so long to solve. But, however, thanks for the support. +1 for detailed answer...

Answer (score 2):

$$(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x)=\frac{\sqrt[5]{1-x^{-1}}-1}{1/x}$$
$\sqrt[5]{1-x^{-1}}-1\rightarrow0$ and $1/x\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. So apply l'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\sqrt[5]{1-\frac{1}{x}}-x)$$
By Applying Binomial Theorem
 ($a<<1 \implies (1-a)^x = (1-xa$))
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x(1-\frac{1}{5x})-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}((x-\frac{1}{5})-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-\frac{1}{5}-x)=-\frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: The most original answer, I think. I did not know how to use Binomial theorem in such cases. I will edit your answer, if you don't mind, by your picture.

Comment: Sure , please do edit it.

Answer (score 1):

A slight twist :

Using bhatthachargee's substitution  $1/x =:h$ , $h \rightarrow 0$, leads to the expression:

$ f(h):=- \dfrac{\sqrt[5]{1-h} -1}{-h}$.

Note:

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(h) = $

$-(\dfrac{d}{dx} \sqrt[5]{x})_{x=1}= -(1/5)$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of derivative at $t=0$. set $t=\frac1x$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}-x)  =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1-t}-1}{t-0} =(\sqrt[5]{1-t})'|_{t=0}=-\frac15 $$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply/divide by the conjugate quintinomial (polynomial factor of $a^5-b^5$). The numerator will turn to $-x^4$, while the denominator will be a sum of five terms of the form $\left(\sqrt[5]{x^5-x^4}\right)^kx^{4-k}$, all asymptotic to $x^4$. Hence the limit is

$$-\frac15.$$

Comment: Is not this what JoseCarlosSantos did and the OP was scared? And why go this difficult method, while there are other simpler methods shown here? One could understand your answering after almost a year if you come up with extraordinary method!

Comment: @farruhota: you are right.