# How do you calculate this limit $\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{f(x)} - \sqrt[m]{g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1xn-1)

Anybody can help me with this limit?
I appreciate any idea. Thanks for providing the information on this great site: D
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{f(x)} - \sqrt[m]{g(x)}$$
where
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$$
and
$$g(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+x^m$$

Comment: The question, once expanded, could be quite similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040

Comment: Funny: the prediction in my last comment is now confirmed. Thus the present question is a duplicate.

Comment: Rewriting the limit as $\lim(f(x)^{1/n}-x)-\lim(g(x)^{1/m}-x)$ - since both limits exist their difference must equal the original limit - and then using the work of the earlier question linked above we know that the answer is $a_{n-1}/n-b_{m-1}/m$.