# How to Solve $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2 + ax} - \sqrt{x^2 + bx}$

Tags: limits

I can't quite figure out how to manipulate this into a determinate form — should I try rationalizing it by multiplying by the conjugate, completing the square, or something like that?

Note: I'm in precalc, so haven't learned any fancy calculus theorems, etc.

Comment: Rationalizing the numerator is a very good start.

Comment: Related: [$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)\!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134581/201168), [$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^2+3x}-\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)\!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/125157/201168), I'm sure you can extend that technique for the general case with $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}$.

Comment: You may also write the limit as, $$\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+ax}-x\right)-\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+bx}-x\right),$$ and then use standard techniques for finding limits of the form, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x.$$ See in particular [this answer by @Sasha](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60574/201168), which should be at your level, assuming you know how to handle the $\Sigma$-notation.

Comment: Actually this turns out to be a duplicate, as I initially guessed, of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62418/201168).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}-\sqrt{x^{2}+bx}&=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}-\sqrt{x^{2}+bx}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}+\sqrt{x^{2}+bx}}\cdot(\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}+\sqrt{x^{2}+bx})\\[6pt]
&=\frac{x^{2}+ax-x^{2}-bx}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}+\sqrt{x^{2}+bx}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(a-b)x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+ax}+\sqrt{x^{2}+bx}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{1+a/x}+\sqrt{1+b/x}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now take the limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Here's an overview of what you should do:

- Rationalize by multiplying by the conjugate.
- Simplify the numerator.
- Factor an $x$ out of the denominator and reduce the whole fraction.
- Take the limit of the new expression.