# Problem about solving infinity limit with square root

Tags: limits

(I)
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(x\sqrt{1+1/x}-x\sqrt{1-1/x}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(x\sqrt{1}-x\sqrt{1}\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(x-x\right)=0$$
(II)
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \left(\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)*\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \frac{2x}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}\right)}=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \frac{2x}{\left(x\sqrt{1+1/x}+x\sqrt{1-1/x}\right)}=$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \frac{2x}{\left(x\sqrt{1}+x\sqrt{1}\right)}=\lim_{x \to \infty } \, \frac{2x}{2x}=1$$

I found these two ways to evaluate this limit. I know the answer is 1. The first one is surely wrong. The question is: why? What is wrong there?

Comment: Because $0\times\infty$ could be anything ... This is basically a situation where you need the second term asymptotic : Your are not allowed to take the limit for one part, and not an other one, and then to continue the computation.

Comment: See Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You took out the $1/x$ part. Surely $1/x\to0$ in the limit, so it may *seem* you can evaluate it to $0$ and then look at the rest of the function in the limit all hunky-dory, but consider  applying that idea to:

$$1=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x\cdot\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(x\cdot0\big) =\lim\,0=0.$$

It doesn't work!

Comment: Ha ha, I like it :)

Comment: @LBg:  And, to get the answer, use the first two terms of the Taylor series $\sqrt{1 \pm \frac 1x} \approx 1\pm \frac 1{2x}$. The first terms cancel to avoid getting infinity and the next ones add to give what you want. The reason the second works is that the denominator avoids the cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

By the same erroneous logic you'd conclude $\rm\:2\: =\: x(1+1/x)-x(1-1/x)\to\: 0$

In your example $\rm\:\displaystyle \sqrt{1+\frac{1}x}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}x}\ =\ \frac{1}x + \frac{1}{8\: x^3} +\: \cdots\:$ which makes the error clear.

If the dominant terms in a sum of series cancel, then you need to look at subsequent terms.