# Calculate $\lim_{n\to{+}\infty}{(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1)

Could someone help me through this problem? 
Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n)}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know any algebraic techniques to rewrite expressions that are written as differences where at least one of the terms is a square root?

Comment: @Peter: I don't think that thread does a very good way of avoiding duplicates, as most people who are asking about problems such as the one in this thread are not yet prepared to comprehend the general solution.

Comment: Yes, "abstract duplicate" has little meaning for students whose background is mainly computational.

Comment: Some other posts about the same limit:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408067/the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtn2-n-n-algebraic-and-intuitive-t
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587457/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783536/prove-that-lim-sqrtn2n-n-frac12
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632157/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n

Comment: I agree with the above comments that it is not very good idea to close this as a duplicate of a much more general question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040. I am voting to reopen. (After the question is reopened, it can be closed as a duplicate of some questions which *really are* duplicates of this one.) See also relevant discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2016/1/30).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have:

$$\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n=\frac{(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n)(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}+n)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}+n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}+n}$$
Therefore:

$$\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1}$$

And since: $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$

It follows that:

$$\boxed{\,\,\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n)=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\,}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Guide**: Rationalize,

$$\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2}\right)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2}}$$

Now divide numerator and denominator by $n$. Remember $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\square}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\square}$.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer that is probably not within the intended scope but it's nice anyway...

Let $x=1/n$. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\to{+}\infty}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}-n} = \lim_{x\to0}{\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+\frac1x}-\frac1x} = \lim_{x\to0}{\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x^2}}-\frac1x} = \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}-\frac1x}= \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x-0}} = f'(0) = \frac12
$$
for $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$.

(There's a small technicality that actually $x\to0^+$ but let's overlook that.)

Comment: You can just take $x \rightarrow 0^+$ the whole way through and conclude as you do, since if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x)$ exists, then so does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} g(x)$ and the two limits are equal.  (Minor point: you have a $1/n$ that should be a $1/x$.)

Comment: @MichaelJoyce, that's the small technicality  I meant. And thanks for finding that typo.

Comment: $x\to 0^+$ is used when you wrote $\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}$ because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.