# Existence of limit of the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$

Tags: limits, radicals

I need to find the limit of the following sequence

$x_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$.

I am having trouble on where to start for this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us your efforts.

Comment: You could start by looking at [this other question from today](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632157/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n), which is **very** similar.

Comment: Some related posts: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136495/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408067/the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtn2-n-n-algebraic-and-intuitive-t
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587457/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783536/prove-that-lim-sqrtn2n-n-frac12
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632157/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n

Comment: Whenever a square root is involved, it is worth to consider multiplying with the conjugate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n^2+1} + n$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the expression by
$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}
$.

Nothing original here - move along now.