# Find the limits : $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x\right) $

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x\right) =\ ? $$

Comment: The sequence $a_n=n$ is divergent. So $\lim a_nb_n$ will exist only if $b_n\to 0$. So, you have to check if the bracketed term converges to zero.  If no, then the limit won't exist.

Comment: The limit here exists and is equal to $-1/4$.

Comment: You might have a look at answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783536/prove-that-lim-sqrtn2n-n-frac12) to see whether you can use a similar approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $t=1/x$, then the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{t^2}\left(\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+t}+1\right).$$
Then use $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+o(x^2)$.
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{t^2}\left(\left(1+\frac{(2t)}{2}-\frac{(2t)^2}{8}+o(t^2)\right)-2\left(1+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{8}+o(t^2)\right)+1\right)=-\frac{1}{4}.$$