# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+n}-n=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Prove **using the definition of a limit** that 
>   $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}_{s_n}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

*Proof:*

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$$\left|\sqrt{n^2+n}-n-\frac12\right|\stackrel{(*)}{=}\left|\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+n}}{2(n+\sqrt{n^2+n})}\right|=\left|\frac{n}{2(n+\sqrt{n^2+n})^2}\right|=\left|\frac{n}{4n^2+4n\sqrt{n^2+n}+2n}\right|<\left|\frac{n}{4n\sqrt{n^2+n}+2n}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n^2+n}+2}\right|$$
Since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\,\,\sqrt{n^2+n}>\sqrt{n}\,$ then
$$\left|\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n^2+n}+2}\right|<\left|\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}\right|<\epsilon\quad\text{ if }\quad n>\frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}.$$

Would this be correct?

---

(*) maybe a simpler way would be to recognize that the numerator is $|s_n|<1?$

Comment: Abit lost at your first expression after =, why don’t you just multiply the original by an expression to complete the difference of squares (and divide, respectively, to compensate), and then just divide numerator and denominator by $n$?

Comment: A more direct way is to note that $$\sqrt{n^2+n}-n=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+1}$$ whose limit is direct, as has been explained tons of times on the site (did you search for duplicates before posting this?).

Comment: @Did not sure where that leads me to... I am supposed to use the definition of a limit to prove the statement, not just compute it. I am able to compute the limit, but that's not the scope here

Comment: @Makina that's what I did, but then dividing by $n$ as mentioned by Did does not really help a whole lot, since I am not trying to compute the limit with limit properties, but show that the equality holds using the definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that lim $(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n) = \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783536/prove-that-lim-sqrtn2n-n-frac12)

Comment: @Nosrati No, it’s not. None of the answers (except the second, which seems overly complicated) use the definition of a limit to answer the question. Please read the problem statement above. Also, I am asking if my proof is correct, thus a proof-verification question.

Comment: What have you done in (*) ?

Comment: "not sure where that leads me to" You would see "where this leads you to" if you tried to compute $\sqrt{n^2+n}-n-\frac12$ using the formula in my comment.

Comment: @DMH16 Your algebra and logic are correct, what part of the proof are you uncertain about?  Can you justify the use of inequalities to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\sqrt{n^2+n}-n{=(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n){\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\over \sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\\={n\over \sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\\={1\over 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}}$$therefore$$\left|{1\over 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}-{1\over 2}\right|{={1\over 2}-{1\over 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}<\epsilon}$$which means that $${ 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}<{1\over {1\over 2}-\epsilon}\\\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}<{{1\over 2}+\epsilon\over {1\over 2}-\epsilon}\\{1+{1\over n}}<{{1\over 4}+\epsilon^2+\epsilon\over {1\over 4}+\epsilon^2-\epsilon}\\{1\over n}<{2\epsilon\over {1\over 4}+\epsilon^2-\epsilon}$$therefore by choosing $$n>{{1\over 4}+\epsilon^2-\epsilon\over 2\epsilon}$$or even $n>{1\over 8\epsilon}$ for small enough $\epsilon$ we obtain $$\left|{1\over 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}-{1\over 2}\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your work, but would my procedure be correct? My question is whether my proof is correct or not.

Comment: Yes. Quite right to me since despite of correction of  your proof (though it is correct), the bound you attained to, overtakes mine :)