# Thought process behind proving a limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My usual way of tackling "prove that $\alpha$ is the limit to the sequence $f(n)$ where $n\in \mathbb N$" is as follows.

First, I establish the necessary condition.

$|f(n)-\alpha|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$

Now, I work my way through to get the condition $n>g(\epsilon)$ and set $N= ceiling( g(\epsilon))$. Now I can state the proof in the traditional manner and it's done.

However, this approach doesn't seem to work for some problems. For instance, if I want to prove that $1/2$ is the limit of the sequence $\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$,

$|\sqrt{n^2+n}-n-1/2| \leq \sqrt{n^2+n}+n+1/2 < \sqrt{n^2+n}+n+1= \sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})<(n+1)(n+n+1)=(n+1)(2n+1)<\epsilon$

Now, according to the strategy I use I must find $g(\epsilon)$ such that $n>g(\epsilon)$ from the above result. But, I can't seem to do it.

My questions are,

1. Does the method I use always work?
2. If so, How can I modify my example to fit that strategy?

Comment: Shouldn't $f$ be $g$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just used $f(n)$ to show that its some function of $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783536/prove-that-lim-sqrtn2n-n-frac12

Comment: @A.Goodier Thank you for directing me to the exact example in my question. I'm curious to know whether the method I use works every time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is there any ambiguity?

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh! you mean when I used it for the second time. You're right. I corrected it.

Comment: Your goal is to ensure $|f(n) - L|<\epsilon$ and the technique is to find a simple $g(n) $ such that ensuring 1) $ |f(n) - L|<g(n) $ and 2) $g(n) <\epsilon $ are easy. You have found wrong $g(n) =(n+1)(2n+1)$ which makes 1) very easy and 2) impossible to ensure. Try finding a suitable $g(n) $.

Comment: Why not write $$n+1/2-\sqrt{n^2+n}=\frac{1}{4n+2+4\sqrt{n^2+n}}<1/4n$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes. Building a better $g(n)$ seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the equation

$$\forall n>N:|f(n)-\alpha|<\epsilon$$

for $N$. This is not exactly the same as finding $n$ such that

$$|f(n)-\alpha|<\epsilon$$ because $f$ might "oscillate" around $\alpha$.

In other terms, find the *largest* solution of

$$f(x)\in(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$$ and take the ceiling.

If $f$ is monotonous around $\alpha$, this amounts to

$$x=\max(f^{-1}(\alpha-\epsilon),f^{-1}(\alpha+\epsilon)),$$ which is your $g(\epsilon)$. But if $f$ has a global minimum/maximum, the correct expression is

$$x=\max\left(\arg\min_{t\in(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)} f(t),\arg\max_{t\in(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)} f(t)\right).$$

---

In practice this approach can be complicated by the need to invert the function or discuss its extrema, and we often content ourselves with simpler, less tight bounds.

Comment: nicely explained.