# Novel solution to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

Solving $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n\,$ is a classic question from Rudin Chapter 3.  Its standard solution (on this site and in solutions manuals) is to [multiply and divide by the conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/783576/414550).  Below I present a novel approach, which to me is clearer and more direct, which I request verification and critique of.

*Note that by placing this in Chapter 3, Rudin is requesting a solution without L'Hopital's rule.*

---

### Solution

Observe that $(n + \frac{1}{2})^2 = n^2 + n + \frac{1}{4}$, so $\sqrt{n^2 + n} = n + \frac{1}{2} + O(\frac{1}{n})$, from which the solution $\frac{1}{2}$ follows immediately.

Or, more explicitly, define $g$ as a function of $n \in \mathbb{N} \to (-1,0)$  such that $2ng + g + g^2 = -\frac{1}{4}$ and $n + \frac{1}{2} + g > 0$. Dividing both sides by $n$ gives $2g + \frac{g}{n} + \frac{g^2}{n} = -\frac{1}{n}$, and since $|g| < 1, \lim_{n \to \infty}g = 0$. Thus, $(n + \frac{1}{2} + g)^2 = n^2 + n$ and $\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n = \frac{1}{2} + g  \to \frac{1}{2}$.

---

### Discussion

I prefer this solution over the conjugate solution for several reasons:

1. It makes clear *why* the result is true: $\sqrt{n^2 + n} \approx n + \frac{1}{2}$.
The absolute error is fixed ($\frac{1}{4}$), so the relative error for large $n$ vanishes.

2. The solution uses no tricks, but is developed by *estimating* $\sqrt{n^2 + n}$, a technique at the heart of analysis. An initial estimate is $n$, but its error is $O(1)$, too large.  So we proceed to $n + \frac{1}{2}$, obvious from $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

Contrast this with the [conjugate solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/783576/414550), which uses a "trick" seemingly pulled out of a hat.  See e.g. [Bergman](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf) (p.25):

> In this problem you can use the ‘‘trick’’ for simplifying such limits from first-year calculus; ask a
> friend if you didn’t learn such a trick. Unfortunately, after the first simplification, the ‘‘obvious’’ next step
> is really an application of continuity of the square root function, and we can’t talk about continuity until
> Chapter 4. So instead...

3. The calculation avoids messy algebraic manipulations.

---

### Questions

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Is it rigorous? My first line simply assumes that to compensate for a constant error, the offset will be $O(\frac{1}{n})$, since it is multiplied by $n$.  I find this convincing but not rigorous.  But I believe my second paragraph, which introduces an explicit $g$ and bounds it, is indeed rigorous.
3. Can the writing be improved?
4. Do you agree with the advantages I've argued?

---

### Conclusions

Great responses! The main conclusions so far are:

1. L.F. and Charles Hudgins showed how the solution above assumes, without proof, that $g$ will always be in $(-1, 0)$
2. Multiple fixes were suggested; by far the best, IMO, is [Will Jagy's idea to add a lower bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4582984/414550)
3. I simplified this approach, giving [a two sentence proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4583691/414550) which I feel is clear, rigorous, and pedagogical, and request verification and critique of.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $g$ is well-defined, or in other words, how do you show that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $g \in (0, 1)$ such that $2ng + g + g^2 = -1/4$?

Comment: g maps the natural numbers to the interval (0,1), but no real number x in the interval (0,1) satisfies 2nx +x +x^2 = -1/4 for n=2, for example. Perhaps you meant for g to map to (-1, 0)?

Comment: I think you'll find that if you try to make this solution more rigorous, you'll either use taylor series, which is a more advanced tool than where this occurs in Rudin, or you'll multiply by the conjugate. The idea is sound and  what you arguably should have in mind when approaching this limit, but I don't see a way to make it rigorous without doing what you want to avoid.

Comment: @GeorgeK. Fixed, indeed I intended $(-1,0)$, thank you for catching that.

Comment: @SRobertJames To elaborate on my answer, I think you'll find that the construction of $g$ is essentially multiplying by the conjugate. While that $g$ arguably has a more analysis flavor to it, I don't think an analyst should necessarily prefer analytical tools to algebraic tools, especially when the algebraic tool is a simple trick well worth memorizing.

Comment: @ L.F. asks "Can you elaborate on why g is well-defined [i.e. a single value in $(-1,0)$]?".  While this seems "obvious" to me algebraically, indeed this assumption does seem to lack rigor: any rigorous proof approach I can think of uses continuity, intermediate value theorem, derivative, etc., or other notions we are not using.  And explicitly solving for $g = \pm \sqrt{n^2  +n} -n - \frac{1}{2}$ is of course simply restating the original problem in different words! Presumably this is what @CharlesHudgins is referring to as well.

Comment: @SRobertJames I retract my previous comments. On further examination, I think I can work what you've done so far into a more (in just my opinion) pedagogically sound form that does pretty much avoid the conjugate.

Comment: Just an alternative suggestion that seems direct, rigorous, and not "tricky". Let $f(n) = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n.$ Then $0 < f(n) < \frac12,$ so $f(n)/n \to 0.$ But $(n + f(n))^2 - n^2 = n,$ therefore $f(n)(2n + f(n)) = n,$ therefore $f(n) = (2 + f(n)/n)^{-1} \to 1/2.$

Comment: Note that for your first point under "discussion," you say the absolute error is constant ($1/4$), but the problem itself is to show the absolute error tends to zero.  I don't know if this is a typo or a conceptual error, but if I take the whole question as a pedagogical argument, this type of confusion would count against your thesis.

Comment: @BrianMoehring My intent is: We wish to estimate $\sqrt{n^2 + n}.$  We use $(n + \frac{1}{2})^2 = n^2 + n + \frac{1}{4}$, which is a constant $\frac{1}{4}$ higher than desired; the sqrt must therefore be slightly less than $n + \frac{1}{2}$.  "Absolute error" refers to error of this _estimate_, not error of the limit.  Please let me know if there's a better way to convey this.

Comment: In my opinion, relying on big $O$ is begging the question and jumping the gun.  Rudin at this point never defined big $O$ and I don't think he *could* have defined big $O$ without first proving all the results that Chapter 3's entire purpose was to expose and deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like explicit inequalities both above and below something. Gives comfort, I think.

For $n \geq 1,$

$$ n + \frac{1}{2}   - \frac{1}{8n} \; \;  \color{blue}{<} \; \; \; \sqrt  { \; n^2 + n \;} \; \; \; \color{blue}{<} \; \; n + \frac{1}{2} $$

because

$$  \left(  n + \frac{1}{2}   - \frac{1}{8n}     \right)^2  \; = \; n^2 + n - \frac{1}{8n}  +  \frac{1}{64n^2} \; = \; \;  n^2 + n - \;  \frac{8n-1}{64n^2}$$

to do the other side,

$$  \left(  n + \frac{1}{2}   - \frac{1}{8n}   + \frac{1}{16n^2}    \right)^2  \; = \; n^2 + n   +  \; \frac{ \; 20n^2 - 4n + 1}{256n^4}$$

so $n \geq 1$ gives

$$ n + \frac{1}{2}   - \frac{1}{8n} \; \;  \color{blue}{<} \; \; \; \sqrt  { \; n^2 + n \;} \; \; \; \color{blue}{<} \; \;   n + \frac{1}{2}   - \frac{1}{8n}   + \frac{1}{16n^2}  $$

The coefficients must match those in the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x},$  but you don't need to know there is such a thing as calculus to find them.

Comment: The "comfort" gained by adding a lower bound is self-evident.  But, pedagogically, how did you find it (that error $< \frac{1}{8n}$)? Where did that bound come from?

Comment: @SRobertJames One way to arrive at that comforting error term is given in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3096264/213690) to the older [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783536) that you cited in the first paragraph of the present question.

Comment: @SRobertJames It is habit at this point, I simply checked the square of $n + \frac{1}{2}  - \frac{c}{n}$  and picked a value for $c$ that I liked. If I wanted a tighter bound above I would check the square of $n + \frac{1}{2}  - \frac{c}{n}  + \frac{d}{n^2}  $

Comment: Fascinating: _When looking for estimates, successively add additional terms of the next power, picking coefficients as appropriate._  That sounds like a very useful tool.  Can we just use $n + 1/2 - 1/n < \sqrt{n^2 + n} < n + 1/2$?  It's simpler and seems just as effective.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as I find the introduction of a lower bound instantly makes the proof simpler and more rigorous, and the technique more broadly applicable.  I did, however, post a [simpler application of this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4583691/414550).  Can you please review?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be to your taste, OP, but here's my attempt to write a proof inspired by what you've already done. This is essentially your idea, just written in a slightly more pedagogical way.

In the year 2022, we may easily graph $\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$ and see that the limit seems to be approaching $\frac{1}{2}$. Inspired by this, we define
$$
r(n) = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n - \frac{1}{2}
$$
We need only show $\lim_{n \to \infty} r(n) = 0$. Observe
$$
\left(r(n) + n + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = n^2 + n
$$
Expanding, we obtain
$$
r(n)^2 + 2nr(n) + r(n) + n^2 + n + \frac{1}{4} = n^2 + n
$$
Then, rearranging
$$
r(n) = -\frac{1}{2n} \left[r(n)^2 + r(n) + \frac{1}{4}\right]
$$
Now we see that it suffices to show that $r(n)$ is bounded. If $r(n)$ is bounded, then the above equation immediately proves $\lim_{n \to \infty} r(n) = 0$. Even better, we get $r(n) = O(\frac{1}{n})$.

How to show that $r(n)$ is bounded? It is obviously bounded below. Here's a trick for the upper bound (discovered by working backward):
$$
n^2 + 2n + 1 > n^2 + n
$$
but then
$$
(n + 1)^2 > n^2 + n
$$
so
$$
n + 1 > \sqrt{n^2 + n}
$$
therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2} > \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n - \frac{1}{2}
$$
which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely *not* a "novel". Just wanted to leave it here as I've constructed a method that doesn't use conjugates.

Let $n=\frac 1x$ as $x\to 0^{+}$. We have:

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt {n^2+n}-n&=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sqrt {\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1x}-\frac 1x\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac {\sqrt {x+1}-1}{x}\end{align}
$$

Now I want to escape the L'Hospital's rule.

Therefore, using the substitution $\sqrt {x+1}=u$ as $u\to 1^{+}$, leads to:

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac {\sqrt {x+1}-1}{x}&=\lim_{u\to 1^{+}}\frac {u-1}{u^2-1}\\
&=\lim_{u\to 1^{+}}\frac {1}{u+1}\\
&=\frac 12.\end{align}
$$

---

Without factorization, finally  substitute $u=v+1$ as $v\to 0^{+}$, we have:

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{u\to 1^{+}}\frac {u-1}{u^2-1}&=\lim_{v\to 0^{+}}\frac {v}{v^2+2v}\\
&=\lim_{v\to 0^{+}}\frac {1}{v+2}\\
&=\frac 12.\end{align}
$$

---

But, I always love using the definition of the derivative:

Using by definition of the derivative, we can also conclude that:

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac {\sqrt {x+1}-1}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac {\sqrt {x+1}-\sqrt 1}{x+1-1}\\
&=\frac {1}{2\sqrt {x}}{\huge{\mid}}_{x=1}\\
&=\frac 12.\end{align}
$$

Comment: You did use conjugates, you just hid it. $\frac{u - 1}{u^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{u + 1}$ is precisely the idea of conjugates.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Controversial. To me, this is factoring.

Comment: The goal with conjugates is to write $(a + b\sqrt{c})^{-1}$ as $x + y\sqrt{c}$ for some $x$ and $y$. We calculate $(a + b\sqrt{c})(a - b\sqrt{c}) = a^2 - b^2c$, which means $x + y\sqrt{c} = \frac{a - b\sqrt{c}}{a^2 - b^2c}$. The only trick we needed was factoring a difference of squares. To me, factoring a difference of squares and multiplying by conjugates are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I wouldn't agree. In this contex the "conjugate" of $a-b$ is not just $a+b$.  For example, if the expression were $\frac {u-1}{u^3-1}$ instead of $\frac {u-1}{u^2-1}$, I would use factorization, not conjugate.

Comment: Precisely. The reason you obtained $\frac{u - 1}{u^2 - 1}$ in your calculation and not $\frac{u - 1}{u^3 - 1}$ is that you used the idea of conjugates to make the proof go through, albeit with extra steps.

Comment: More explicitly, $\frac{1}{u + 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 1}$, which is just the inverse conjugate of $\sqrt{x + 1} - 1$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I presented $2$ different variants. Now, your "conjugate" argument seems not valid. I also defend this idea: "conjugate" comes from factoring, but factoring doesn't come from "conjugate".

Comment: You make good use of substitution of variable that goes to a limit.  This is a common technique for integration, but less familiar for limits, especially when it necessitates going to a limit from one side.  Can you provide a pointer or reference that goes over this technique more? Or, at the least, a theorem or identity that justifies it?

Comment: @SRobertJames  IMHO, using *the definition of the derivative* seems neat and rigorous trick to me. I always love this trick. Because, this uses just a definition!

Comment: Yes, ny question about substitution of variable in limits is about the earlier solutions.

Comment: @SRobertJames I just constructed these substitutions myself while looking at the limit.But, I can justify. My purpose in using the substitution $n=\frac 1x$ was to get a "fractional" expression.Because, at least I could use L'Hopital's rule or the definition of the derivative.Then I used $\sqrt {x+1}=u$, Because I wanted to use"rational fractional expression" instead of the "irrational fractional expression".Finally, I used $u:=v+1$ to solve "indeterminate" form.But, you can also apply the L'Hopital's rule to the final limit (containing $x$).However, I chose to use the definition of derivative

Answer (score 1):

*Drawing on [Will Jagy's excellent idea to introduce a lower bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4582984/414550), a **revised solution** is below.  Please verify and critique.*

Observe that $(n+\frac 1 2)^2 = n^2 + n + \frac 1 4$, suggesting that $\sqrt{n^2 + n} = n + \frac 1 2 - O(\frac 1 n)$ and the desired limit is $\frac 1 2$.  To prove this, we need a lower bound on $\sqrt{n^2 + n}$.

The quantity $n + \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 n$ is a lower bound, since $(n + \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 n)^2 = n^2 + n - \frac 7 4 - \frac 1 n + \frac 1 {n^2} < n^2 + n$ for $n \geq 1$.  Since $n + \frac 1 2 - n > \sqrt {n^2 +n} - n > n + \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 n - n$, the Squeeze Theorem tells us that $\lim \sqrt {n^2 +n} - n = \frac 1 2.$

Comment: yes, you do not require optimal coefficients to just show , umm,  shrinkage in where the possible limit is allowed to be. I was surprised to learn that this idea is a staple in French mathematics education, with  a particular description probably going back to Cauchy.  Maybe I can find that  agin

Comment: found it, a question and then my request of Jean-Marie    /////////////////      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391704/what-are-suites-adjacentes-called-in-english
   //////////////////////   
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393211/how-to-show-that-euler-constant-lies-in-0-1     /////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

It’s an old technique to replace $a-b$ with $\frac{a-b}{\frac{a+b}{a+b}}$ or $\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$.

This is especially useful with square roots. $n=\sqrt{n^2},$so you get $\frac{n^2+n-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1}$.

That not also gives you a way to the limit, it also lets you evaluate the expression with little rounding error).

Well, you replaced the limit with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{(n+1/2)^2-1/4}-n$$  Which looks quite like $\frac12,$ but needs proving.

Comment: Could you please use MathJax to format equations?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than answer your numbered subquestions in detail, I suggest here
a simple and clear alternative proof, using what I think is
essentially the same idea. (It occurred to me in the context of a more
complicated recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4580934),
and I initially posted it only as a
[comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783536#comment9656815_3096264)
on an answer to a similar question from 2019, but then I was reminded
that you had recently used a similar idea.)

Let $m = n + \frac12,$ and
$$
f(m) = \sqrt{m^2 - \frac14} = \sqrt{n^2 + n}.
$$
Then $0 < f(m) < m,$ and
$$
m(m - f(m)) < (m + f(m))(m - f(m)) = m^2 - f(m)^2 = \frac14,
$$
therefore
$$
0 < m - f(m) <\frac 1{4m},
$$
therefore $m - f(m) \to 0,$ i.e.
$$
\frac12 + n - \sqrt{n^2 + n} \to 0,
$$
which gives the required result.

Comment: It's arguable whether this is any different from the standard idea "multiply and divide by the conjugate" (as referred to in the OP); but because it occurred to me quite naturally, it might seem natural to others, too, rather than looking like a "trick".