# Test for convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(n^3+1)^{1/3} - n\}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to expand and test this $\{(n^3+1)^{1/3} - n\}$ for convergence/divergence.

The edited version is: Test for convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(n^3+1)^{1/3} - n\}$

Comment: Yes, it converges as $n\to 2$. But presumably that isn't what you mean, so you need to provide more information, and explain what you've tried or thought about so far.

Comment: It is term of an infinite series (n is a natural no.). Interestingly in one book it is given to be divergent and in another it is convergent. BUT none tells how?

Comment: So, you want to consider $n\to \infty$. You should add that to the question - the "edit" button for your question is just below the "limit" and "convergence" tags, on the lower left. Now, what have you tried on this problem so far, if anything?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040/264) and consequently should be closed.

Comment: Well! I am editing the question.  I think I got the answer from avatar BUT I still have a little bit of doubt about his answer.  I am writing the doubt as a comment to his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By direct inspection, for every pair of real numbers $A$ and $B$,
$$
A^3 - B^3 = (A-B) (A^2+AB+B^2).
$$
Choose now $A=\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$ and $B=n$. Then
$$
(n^3+1)^{1/3} - n = \frac{n^3+1-n^3}{(n^3+1)^{2/3} + n (n^3+1)^{1/3}+n^2} \sim \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
as $n \to +\infty$. The limit is therefore zero.

Comment: Check the denominator, the $A^2$ term

Comment: I agree with you Siminore!  But your A^2 and A term appears to be wrong in index.  There should be '2/3' and '1/3' index respectively

Comment: Is it better now? Thank you!

Comment: It's wrong, it should be either $\sim 1/(3 n^2)$, or $O(1/n^2)$

Comment: We will never agree on the use of symbols :-) I learned that $a_n \approx b_n$ means that $a_n / b_n \to 1$, and that $a_n \sim b_n$ that $a_n / b_n$ tends to a limit different than zero (and finite). It seems hard to find a set of symbols that everybody can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=1/n$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(n^3+1)}^{1/3}-n=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{(1+y^3)^{1/3}-1}{y}$. Using L'Hopital's Rule, this limit evaluates to $0$.Hence, the expression converges.
You can also see that as $n$ increases, the importance of $1$ in the expression ${(n^3+1)}^{1/3}-n$ decreases and $(n^3+1)^{1/3}$ approaches $n$.Hence, the expression converges to $0$(as verified by limit).
  For the series part as @siminore pointed out,this difference ${(n^3+1)}^{1/3}-n$ is of the order of $1/n^2$,therefore, the sum of these is of the order of this sum :$\sum_{1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ which  is $= {\pi}^2/6$. Thus the series is bounded and hence converges .

Comment: Thanks avatar.  The books I have do not mention that a series converges if its 'n'th term tends to 0 (or any finite no.).  The sequence does converge but does it prove the series converges?

Comment: A necessary condition for a series $\sum_n a_n$ to converge is that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n=0$. But this condition is far from being also sufficient.

Comment: A sequence converges if its nth term converges,but for convergence of series, that nth term must converge to $0$ and even this is a necessary condition but not sufficient.

Comment: In that case (condition not sufficient) the convergence of the 'n'th term does not serve our purpose.  Am I right? How about comparing the series with another known series?

Comment: That's what i have done in my answer.I have edited it.Check it.

Comment: if you can bound the series by another convergent series, then the given series converges too.

Comment: Will you please explain $\sum_{1}{∞}frac{1}{n^6} which is ≈π6/945$.

Comment: I edited my answer again. check it.

Comment: For summation part visit http://math2.org/math/expansion/power2.htm

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we note is that, as $n\to \infty$ the term $(n^3+1)^{1/3}$ is of order $n$, which is cancelled by the other term, hence we must ask about the next order approximation.

Now, $ (n^3+1)^{1/3} = n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}$ and $(1+x)^{1/3} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}x + O(x^2)$, hence

$$ (n^3+1)^{1/3} - n = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{n^2}+O(n^{-5})$$

Hence, the series converge.

(If you want an explicit bound, you can just use $ (1+x)^{1/3} < 1+x$ for $x>0$, so you can compare to the series $\sum 1/n^2$ which you're supposed to know is convergent)