# Computing limits which involve square roots, such as $\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Is there a general strategy for this? For example I'm working on the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n $$

I have a simple argument to show that this limit is less than or equal to 1/2, but I can't get much further because it's difficult for me to manipulate the square root symbol. Here is the argument:
$\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n \lt \sqrt{n^2 +n + \frac{1}{4}} - n = n+\frac{1}{2} - n = 1/2$

Comment: You can try a series expansion.

Comment: Just write $\sqrt{n^2 + n} = n \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow n$

Comment: @vonbrand: the correct answer is $\frac12$, not $0$. Just because $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$, it doesn't follow that $n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - n \to 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1)

Comment: Please consider browsing the [faq] tag before posting a question. [To anyone who comes across this comment, I know this question is old]

Comment: @Aryabhata The ubiquitous multiply-by-conjugate trick is clearly explained here, and not so much in the linked post, because of the greater generality of the latter. A special case is not always a duplicate.

Comment: @Normal: I suggest you read this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions and the linked question by Bill D. Special case vs general case is a common objection to such closings, but such closings [i.e. closed as minor variations] are fine IMO. It does not have to be an exact dupe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n & = (\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n} + n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n} +n} \\
& = \frac{n^2+n-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2 + n} + n} \\
& = \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n} + n}{n}} \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} + 1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about that trick!

Comment: @Mark: When in doubt, multiply by $1$, or add $0$. :)

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n}+n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}+n}=...=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}+n}=...=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Just noting that this is the same solution as @gnometorule for anyone who is skimming over the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

By the bound stated in the problem, it suffices to show that the limit is $\ge \frac{1}{2}$. This proof is a lot worse than the others but maybe a good exercise in mean value theorem which is why I'm writing it up. Intuitively we want a way to estimate how far $\sqrt{n^2 + n}$ is from $n$. But the mean value theorem along with concavity gives exactly the approximation we need.

Let $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n^2 + x}$
$$f_n'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(n^2 + x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ Now use the mean value theorem
$$\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n = f_n(n) - f_n(0) = f_n'(x^*)n$$  where $x^* \in (0, n)$ (and I have suppressed dependence of $x^*$ on $n$). Then by the fact that $f_n'$ is decreasing, we get
$$ f_n'(n) \lt f_n'(x*)$$
Multiplying by $n$ on both sides
$$ n f_n'(n) < n f_n'(x^*) = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$$
Substituting 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{n}{(n^2 + n)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \lt \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{(1 + 1/n)}^{\frac{1}{2}}} \lt \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$$

And actually the upper bound of $1/2$ could have been found using the same method.

Comment: I think this is essentially the strategy suggested by @Amzoti with expansion being just the first order taylor approximation = MVT.