# Calculating $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\sqrt{x^2-3x}-x)$

Tags: limits, radicals

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-3x}$ and $g(x) = x$. Calculate the following limits, showing all working.

I've done the first two -

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{x^2-3x}=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\
=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x}}{x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}=1$$

How do I calculate this one?

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x)-g(x))$$

Comment: could you please verify that the question is not changed by the edit?

Comment: I think the limit the OP is asking about has no multiplication by $\,x\,$ ...

Comment: For the one I'm trying to work out, it shouldn't be x is approaching NEGATIVE infinity, just infinity.

Comment: Upon checking, the last limit is at $x\to+\infty$, not $x\to-\infty$. (If only users editing posts could be more careful, it seems an awful lot of misprints are introduced this way.)

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1) which deals with a more general version of this problem. Many similar limits can be found in the posts which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040).

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799055/calculate-the-limit-of-sqrtn2-3n-n-as-n-rightarrow-infty) is very similar, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your second one is incorrect, since $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ for all $x<0$. Hence:
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x}}{-\sqrt{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}=-1
$$

---

For the last one, we multiply by the conjugate:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x)-g(x)]
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left[ \sqrt{x^2-3x}-x \right] \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\left(\sqrt{x^2-3x}-x\right) \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x} \right] \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{(x^2-3x)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{-3x}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{-3x}{\sqrt{x^2(1-\frac3x)}+x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{-3x}{x\sqrt{1-\frac3x}+x} \qquad \text{since }\sqrt{x^2}=x \text{ for all }x>0\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{1-\frac3x}+1} \\
&= \dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{1-0}+1} \\
&= \dfrac{-3}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Adriano, shouldn't it be 3/2?

Comment: Not unless there is a typo in the question (which seems likely, if you're sure that that's the answer).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\{f(x)-g(x)\}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\{\sqrt{x^2-3x}-x\}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-3h}-1}h(\text{ putting } x=\frac1h)$$

Now this can be handled in at least three ways :

**Method** $1:$

Taylor expansion:
 $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1-3h)^{\frac12}-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-3h\cdot\frac12+O(h^2)-1}h=-\frac32$$

**Method** $2:$

L'Hosiptals' Rule :

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1-3h)^{\frac12}-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-3h}}\cdot(-3)}1=-\frac32$$

**Method** $3:$

Rationalizing the numerator like Adriano,
 $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-3h}-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1-3h)-1}{h(\sqrt{1+3h}+1)}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-3}{\sqrt{1+3h}+1}(\text{ Cancelling } h\text{ as }h\ne0\text{ as }h\to0  )$$

$$=-\frac32$$

Comment: lim [f (x)-g (x)] = [{√(x² -3x)}-x] = x*[{(1-(3/x)}^(1/2) -1] = [x*(3/2x)+.....higher powers of (1/x)] = 3/2 ?

Comment: @KatieMalone, Could you please have a look into the edited answer

Comment: There is no negative in the last one I am working on. As I understood, the answer should be 3/2 but I am a little stuck on the working.

Comment: @KatieMalone, first of all, I really doubt the existence of $x$ as multiplier in the last question if the answer needs to be finite. Now, if the method is right, so should be the answer. Have you find anything wrong in the three methods?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Would you be able to do me a favor by removing the negatives from your working? And yes! It is not multiplies by x.

Comment: @KatieMalone, thanks for your rectification. I think the answer is $-\frac32$. I repeat : "Have you find anything wrong in the three methods?"

Comment: I think they look okay to me!

Answer (score 0):

To find $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-3x}-x:$

Rewrite $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-3x}-x=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}-1\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}-1}{1/x}.$ This gives an indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$ form. Applying L'Hopital gives us:

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{3/x^2}{2 \sqrt{1-3/x}}\right)}{(-1/x^2)}=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{-3}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}}=\frac{-3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

As
$$f(x)-g(x)=\sqrt{x^2-3x}-x$$
$$=\frac{x^2-3x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x}$$
$$=\frac{-3x}{\sqrt{x^2-3x}+x}$$
$$=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{1-3/x}+1}$$
Now when $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ we get
$$=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{1-0}+1}$$
$$=\frac{-3}{2}$$