# Calculate the limit of $\sqrt{n^2-3n}-n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Calculate the limit of $\sqrt{n^2-3n}-n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $.

I'm having a hard time trying to simplify this expression in order to be able to get the limit of it.

I have $\sqrt{n^2-3n}-n=\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{3}{n})}-n=n\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{n}}-n=n(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{n}}-1)$

Don't think that this gives me anything useful, can anybody give me some hints.

Comment: $2n$ or $3n$ ? Please edit.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Edited my post.

Comment: In my answer, change $2$ by $3$. The approach is general. Cheers.

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1) and also some [questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040). In particular, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469617/calculating-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2-3x-x) is very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* multiply and divide by the ‟conjugate” expression $\sqrt{n^2-3n}+n$.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as recommended above, or you can try this:

Pull the $n$ out of the square root to give
$$(n^2 -2n)^{1/2} -n = n((1-2/n)^{1/2}-1) \\
=n[(1 + {1 \over 2}{-2 \over n} - {1 \over 4}({-2 \over n})^2 + \ ...) -1]
= -1 - 1/n + \ ... $$
and thus when you take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, you get the limit of $-1$.

Hope this helps - if it does, please remember to upvote and/or accept my answer! :)

Comment: Sorry, your question initially had a $2$ in the square root, not a $3$! The method is the same, just the answer is $-3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You found

$$n(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{n}}-1)$$
now use the Taylor approximation $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_01+\alpha x$ so
$$n(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{n}}-1)\sim_\infty n\times \left(-\frac12\frac 3n\right)=-\frac32$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way:
Write what you got as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$ and use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: That looks more fun that conjugates hahaha

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Another way : write $$\sqrt{n^2-2n}-n=n \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{n}}-n=n(\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{n}}-1)$$ and remember that, when $x$ is small compared to $1$, $$\sqrt{1+x}\simeq 1+\frac{x}{2}$$ So, replace in the last expression $x$ by $-\frac{2}{n}$, expand and multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Try completing the square to give $$\sqrt {n^2-3n}-n=\sqrt {\left(n-\frac32\right)^2-\frac 94}-n$$ which you should be able to show goes to $$n-\frac 32-n=-\frac 32$$