# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals

Evaluate the following limit:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n)$$
So far I've come up with this: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n)$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2(1+\frac{1}{4n}})-2n)$ 
= $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{4n}})-2n)$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n(\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{4n}})-1))$. I think it's pretty clear from here that this goes to infinity, but how can I justify that the 2n grows stronger to infinity than the part in the brackets goes to zero? I know standard rules about exponential functions growing harder than polynomials, but not about this.

Comment: See also: [How would you prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n)=\frac14$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/483481)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasoning is not correct, and the limit is not infinity. Instead, multiply by the conjugate on top and bottom:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4n^2 + n } - 2n &= \Big(\sqrt{4n^2 + n} - 2n\Big) \frac{\sqrt{4n^2 + n} + 2n}{\sqrt{4n^2 + n} + 2n} \\
&= \frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2 + n} + 2n} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 + \frac 1 n}+2}
\end{align*}