# Evaluate limit of the type : $\infty - \infty$?

Tags: limits

Evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x+7)^\frac{1}{17}-x^\frac{1}{17}$$

---

I don't know where to begin to be honest. I know that when a limit evaluates to:

$$\infty-\infty$$

it simply means that it the limit is still indeterminate and could be anything. I cannot see a way to rewrite the limit so that it can be resolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1)

Comment: (With $x^{1/17}$ instead of $x$.)

Comment: the usual trick here is to turn something where we are subtracting two infinities into something where we are dividing two infinities.  So, what you do is you multiply the top and bottom by the "conjugate" of the top, since multiplying anything by something of the form $\frac a a=1$ doesnt change it. I'm not sure of the proper fraction for this equation to simplify the algebra, hopefully someone is, but its a general technique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem:
$$
(x+7)^{1/17}-x^{1/17}=\frac{1}{17}\,(\xi_x)^{-16/17}\cdot7
$$
with $x\le \xi_x\le x+7$.

Comment: This is definitely what I should have done since I was just working with the mean value theorem.

Comment: The simplest. +1.

Answer (score 7):

$$(x+c)^\alpha=x^\alpha\cdot(1+c/x)^\alpha=x^\alpha(1+c\alpha/x+o(1/x))=x^\alpha+c\alpha x^{\alpha-1}+o(x^{\alpha-1})$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Use the identity $$a^n-b^n={(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+ \ldots +a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1})}$$
with $a=(x+7)^\frac{1}{17},\;\; b=x^\frac{1}{17}, \;\;n=17.$

Answer (score 0):

Using the Hint of Hans Lundmark, let $u=\sqrt[17]{x}$ and rewrite the limit as:

$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\sqrt[17]{u^{17}+1}-u$$

Then,
$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[17]{1+\frac{1}{u^{17}}}-1}{\frac{1}{u}}$$

Now, substitute again to $y=\frac{1}{u}$, so $u\to\infty\Rightarrow y\to0$ and
$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sqrt[17]{1+y^{17}}-1}{y}$$

Using L'Hopital,
$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sqrt[17]{1+y^{17}}-1}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{17\cdot\sqrt[17]{1+y^{17}}^{16}}\cdot17y^{16}}{1}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y^{16}}{\sqrt[17]{1+y^{17}}^{16}}=0$$