# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to ∞}\left (\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}-x\right)$

Tags: analysis, limits

I am interested in evaluation $\lim_{x\to ∞} \left(\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}-x \right)$.

I tried to multiply it by ($\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}+x$) but didn't seem like it did worked.

Comment: You can write \infty for the $\infty$ symbol. :)

Comment: Try multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}+x}$ instead

Comment: Famous duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040/201168). See also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269766/201168).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+4x+1}-x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+4x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}+x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x+1}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+x}\\= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that does not rationalize the term of interest.  Rather, we rely on the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).  To that end, we proceed.

Applying the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) to the square root reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}-x\right)&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\left(1+\frac{4x+1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}-x\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{4x+1}{2x}+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)\\\\
&=2
\end{align}$$