# How to calculate this limit at infinity?

Tags: limits, radicals

How would you calculate this limit:

$$
\lim_{a\to ∞} \left(\sqrt {x^2+a}-\sqrt {a}\right)
$$

The answer is 0 but I have no idea how to get to it.

Comment: try rationalising

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1) and also at some posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $$\lim_{a\to ∞} \left(\sqrt {x^2+a}-\sqrt {a}\right)=\lim_{a\to ∞} \left(\sqrt {x^2+a}-\sqrt {a}\right)\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x^2+a}+\sqrt{a}}\bigg)$$

$$=\lim_{ a\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a}+\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try multiply with $$1=\frac{ \sqrt{x^2+a}+\sqrt{a} }{ \sqrt{x^2+a}+\sqrt{a} }$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $\sqrt{x^2+a} + \sqrt{a}\over {\sqrt{x^2+a} + \sqrt{a}}$, then use $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$:

$$
\lim_{a\to ∞} \left(\sqrt {x^2+a}-\sqrt {a}\right) = \lim_{a\to ∞} \left((\sqrt {x^2+a}-\sqrt {a}) ( \sqrt{x^2+a} + \sqrt{a})\over {\sqrt{x^2+a} + \sqrt{a}}\right) = \lim_{a\to ∞} \left(x^2   \over {\sqrt{x^2+a} + \sqrt{a}}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the physicist in me likes this approach
$$
\sqrt{x^2+a}-\sqrt{a} =\sqrt{a}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a}}-\sqrt{a}
$$
then we can expand 
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a}}\to 1+\frac{x^2}{2a} +O(a^{-2})\approx 1+\frac{x^2}{2a} 
$$
then we have
$$
\sqrt{a}+\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{a}}+O(a^{-3/2})-\sqrt{a}
$$
so in the limit $\frac{x^2}{a}<<1$ then we have
$$
\sqrt{x^2+a}-\sqrt{a}\approx \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{a}}
$$
now take $a\to\infty$.

Or rationalize the numerator as per the other quicker/more beautiful answers show.