# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}-x\right)$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}-x\right)$$

The answer is $2$ but I don't know how to evaluate it

Comment: But theres nothing on rhs no equality or is it a limits question

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a limit as $x\to\text{something}$ of that function? If so, what's "$\text{something}$"? Also, **share with us your attempts**.

Comment: I assume he means $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} $ of that given equation,  it would fit the answer.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30040/201168).

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}=x\sqrt{1+4/x+1/x^2}\approx x(1+2/x+1/2x^2)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there  is a minus $x$

Comment: Multiply by $A/A$ where $A=\sqrt {x^2+4 x+1}+x$.

Comment: Completing the square is the easiest way to see it, I think.

Comment: @Nehorai: I know, I didn't give the complete solution.

Comment: @Lucas andre don't forget to accept one of the answers clicking the 'V' in the left side of the answer, and also to vote

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}\right)-x\right)=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(x^2+4x +1\right)-x^2}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}\right)+x}=$$
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}=\frac{4x +1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}+x}=\frac 42=2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}-x\right)}{1}$$

Multiply nominator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}+x$

$$\require{cancel}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(\cancel{x^2}+4x +1\right)\cancel{-x^2}}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}\right)+x}$$
$$=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{4x +1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x\ +1}+x}$$

Divide nominator and denominator by $x$

$$=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{4 +\overbrace{1/x}^{\to 0}}{\sqrt{1+\underbrace{4/x}_{\to 0} +\underbrace{1/x^2}_{\to0}}+1}=\frac {4} {1+1}=\color{red}2$$