# prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1}=\frac{n}{m}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to find a way to prove this:

EDIT: without using LHopital theorem.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1}=\frac{n}{m}.$$
Honestly, I didn't come with any good idea.

We know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}x^{1/m}$ is $1$.

I'd love your help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest playing around with various inequalities and using the squeeze theorem. For example, the inequality $(1+\epsilon)^a\leq 1+a\epsilon$ when $a,\epsilon >0$, helps quite a bit.

Comment: Like Jim said, rather than the accepted answer, a more analytical way of thinking this would be using Taylor expansion: writing $x^{1/m} = (1 + \Delta x)^{1/m} = 1 + \frac{1}{m} \Delta x + o(\Delta x^2)$, the higher order terms will disappear when letting $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ in that quotient you have.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter:  I made that edit almost seven years ago. And if you take a look at my profile, perhaps you will see that your bit of helpful advice is... misguided in its intended target. I mean, really....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You [introduced `\displaystyle`](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/36083/revisions#spacer-7153f959-491f-4ee3-b43c-8ee88ca7e4fc) to the title of this post, so I tagged you without looking at your profile.  I do the same for every edit of this kind.  You may take a look at my edit history to know more.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: And given that you were addressing a 7 year old edit, perhaps you could have taken the few seconds to see if your scolding was perhaps a bit past the statute of limitations. By the way: taking a seven-year-old post and **bumping** it to the front page with an edit that addresses nothing but  style is likewise rather frowned upon. Its most recent prior edit was a year ago. Perhaps you might also consider that next time you decide to do edits without doing much follow-up or thinking about them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $ If you change variables $\rm\ z = x^{1/n} $ then the limit reduces to a very simple first derivative calculation. See also some of my [prior posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+derivative+limit) for  further examples of limits that may be calculated simply as first derivatives.

Answer (score 6):

You can rewrite the limit as
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} {{x^{1\over m} - 1 \over x - 1} \over {x^{1 \over n} - 1 \over x- 1}}$$
By the quotient rule for limits this is exactly
$${\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} {x^{1 \over m} - 1 \over x - 1} \over \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} {x^{1 \over n} - 1 \over x - 1}}$$
But notice that for any $\alpha$, ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} {x^{\alpha} - 1 \over x - 1}}$ is just the limit of difference quotients giving the definition of the derivative of the function $x^{\alpha}$ when evaluated at $x = 1$. So the limit is $\alpha$. So the limit in this question will be ${\displaystyle {{1 \over m} \over {1 \over n}} = {n \over m}}$.

Answer (score 1):

One thing about limits is that, if they exist, the "speed" at which you approach them doesn't matter. That is to say, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1} = \lim_{x^{1/n}\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{y^{n/m}-1}{y-1}$. If you then apply L'Hopital's rule, you should get your answer.

Comment: If you're going to apply L'Hopital, why not do it immediately? But instead of invoking L'Hopital in your last step, one can observe that your transformed limit is a derivative at 1, see Bill Dubuque's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)? It is useful in evaluating the limits of fractions such as yours.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use it in this stage. I need to teach this someone who can't use LHopital right now.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1} = \frac{e^{\log(x^{1/m})}-1}{e^{\log(x^{1/n})}-1} = \frac{e^{\frac1{m}\log(x)}-1}{e^{\frac1{n}\log(x)}-1} = \frac{e^{\frac1{m}\log(x)}-1}{\log(x)} \frac{\log(x)}{e^{\frac1{n}\log(x)}-1}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1/m}-1}{x^{1/n}-1} = \lim_{\log(x) \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac1{m}\log(x)}-1}{\log(x)} \frac{\log(x)}{e^{\frac1{n}\log(x)}-1} = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac{y}{m}}-1}{y} \frac{y}{e^{\frac{y}{n}}-1} = \frac1{m} \frac1{\frac1{n}} = \frac{n}{m}$$

Comment: isn't this a _really_ indirect way of saying "use $lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} (1+\epsilon)^{1/m} = 1+(\epsilon/m)+O(\epsilon^2)$

Comment: @samanwita: I have used the fact $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^y-1}{y} = 1$ which is probably one of the first limits people are taught.

Comment: Did you mean that $x$ tends to 1 in the second row?

Comment: @Nir: Yes. Thanks.