# How to explain indeterminations, and some aprpoaches to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, for middle school students?

Tags: infinity, indeterminate-forms

---

### Question: how to explain the undefinitions $0^0$ and $\frac{0}{0}$ for Middle school students??

---

I am a math teacher and I don't know how to answer properly when studens ask me why some operations give **undefined/indetermination** (the most frequent are $0^0$ and $\frac{0}{0}$) or why division by zero result infinity. So most of time a avoid to answer such because I am affraid to confuse them more with too complicated explanations. Some student understand most explanations, but others have more difficulties.

To explain division by zero I try to use their intuition, making divisions by factor every time smaller, so I get a *kind* of limit without mentionig it (I say: "dividing by a number every time smaller, what you get is always a bigger one, tendind to a huge number, the $\pm\infty$"). But still, some continue to asking me: "I understand that dividing nothing by any number, the result is nothing for each" ($\frac{0}{n} = 0$, division of finite by zero). "Why is that, if I divide any number by no one, I should get infinity?" (these students continue to think that we should expect no change after such a division).

I tried once to explain $\frac{0}{0}$ with an simple equation like $\frac{a}{0}=b$. In this case we can use algebrism to write $a = 0\cdot b$, which means $a$ was already known ($~=0$), and we can say nothing about $b$, that is, it is undefined (in fact, I am not quite sure this is an satisfactory answer).

And what about the other indeterminations if some clever student asks me? Can someone help me out with this doubt? I hope I made myself clear.

I was searching for other similar questions but didn't find what I was looking for. Some interesting posts related are:
[Ways to solve indeterninations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125161/ways-to-solve-these-types-of-indeterminations); [Solving indetermination in limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37948/solving-indetermination-in-limit); [Two square roots in an indeterminate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58926/two-square-roots-in-an-indeterminate/58929#58929). See also [Mathematics in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics)).

Comment: You should also consider participating in the public beta for [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) for questions like these. They would appreciate your support.

Comment: $0^0$ is just $1$. The thing that's indeterminate is not $0^0$, it's $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @J.W.Perry: oh nice, actually I did not know about this plataform.. i Will search also enter there and interact.  I thought "Area 51" was a Q&A for enthusiasts of science fiction, and maybe "X-files" :b, but certainly I was wrong.

Comment: It is new, and it is in public beta, so we have no direct path to migrate the question there. You may get responses here, but if you post on *Mathematics Educators*, we will want to delete it here assuming no one provides answers here (cross posting is not desirable). Welcome to StackExchange. If I were you I would wait for responses here before cross posting :)

Comment: @J.W.Perry Yes, so far I won't duplicate my post. I have one answer already. Ty

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: well, now I'm confused. I always thought $0^0$ was an indetermination... How you'd explain the following: $0^0 = 0^{1-1} = 0^1\cdot 0^{-1}=\frac{0}{0} \therefore$ **indeterminate** ? See also the answer bellow.

Comment: @Claudia: the second equality doesn't hold because $0^{-1}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest as an informal explanation for some kinds of indeterminate forms, though it may be less helpful for others.

If you try to evaluate $0^0$ by concentrating on the exponent, you would probably say, "anything to the power $0$ is $1$, therefore the answer is $1$".  On the other hand, if you concentrated on the base, you would probably say "$0$ to any power is $0$, therefore the answer is $0$".  The fact that you can get contradictory answers in this way is what makes it an indeterminate form.

Similarly, for "$\frac00$", concentrating on the numerator suggests an answer of $0$ while concentrating on the denominator suggests an answer of $\infty$.  In this case however, I would be very careful not to let the students believe that $\infty$ is **ever** a sensible answer to an arithmetic question.

Comment: thaks for the answer... you gave me good points to think of.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following link from "Dr. Math" for some reasonable and pretty simple explanations that refrain from mentioning limits: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221161514/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.divideby0.html) ...one answer I like is this: Consider a physical description of division in the positive integers.  For instance, we can consider $10 \div 2 = 5$ as a statement that if you divide, for instance, $10$ blocks into groups of $2$ blocks, you end up with $5$ groups. Consider doing this with $10 \div 0 = ?$ ...how many groups of zero blocks can we divide $10$ blocks into?

Comment: yes, in fact it is a good way to see it. Thanks for the answer!